# Looking for a solution to stream dynamic changes in JSON data on to browser without refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, socket.io

I have a node.js / next.js api built that essentially does a bunch of stuff after the user submits text into a form on the front end. One of the things it does is write stage completion messages periodically to a JSON file to signify the completion of certain stages.

my api looks something like this

```
import dbConnect from '../../../lib/dbConnect'
import Demo from '../../../models/Demo'
import fs from 'fs'
import shell from  'shelljs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const {
    method,
    body,
  } = req

  await dbConnect()

  switch (method) {
    case 'GET':
      try {
        const demos = await Demo.find({}) 
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: demos })
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false })
      }
      break
    case 'POST':
      try {
          const initialjson = '[]'
          const timestamp = Date.now();
          // stage 1
          if (shell.exec('./initial_checks.sh').code !== 0) {
            shell.echo('Sorry stage failed');
            shell.exit(1);
          };
          const objSuccess1 = JSON.parse(initialjson);
          objSuccess1.push("Stage 1 complete", + timestamp);
          const finalJSONSuccess1 = JSON.stringify(objSuccess1);
          fs.writeFileSync('success-stage.json', finalJSONSuccess1);
          // stage 2
          if (shell.exec('./secondary_checks.sh').code !== 0) {
            shell.echo('Sorry stage failed');
            shell.exit(1);
          };
          const objSuccess2 = JSON.parse(initialjson);
          objSuccess2.push("Stage 2 complete", + timestamp);
          const finalJSONSuccess2 = JSON.stringify(objSuccess2);
          fs.writeFileSync('success-stage.json', finalJSONSuccess2);
        const demo = await Demo.create(
          req.body
        )
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: demo })
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false })
      }
      break
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false })
      break
  }
}
```

I am using socket.io, my server.js file is
server.js

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

let port = 3000;

const fs = require('fs')
const data = fs.readFileSync('success-stage.json', 'utf8')

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("now", {
    message: data
  });
});

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  app.all("*", (req, res) => {
    return nextHandler(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Ready on port: " + port);
  });
});
```

and here is the pages/index.js file

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const socket = useRef();
  const [hello, setHello] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io();
    socket.current.on("now", (data) => {
      setHello(data.message);
    });
  }, []);

  return <h1>{hello}</h1>;
}
```

so at this point we are seeing the 2nd message from my JSON file match what is rendered on the frontend when I build my application. It looks like this

```html
["Stage 2 complete",1664289144513]
```

I am wondering how I can stream this data onto the front end for clients without having to refresh the page? I need it to show the current stage's success message... There are 5 total stages, so i guess i am looking for a way to either stream data or maybe to revalidate the browser window like every second without having to refresh... is this possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks in advance for your time everyone...

Answer (score 1):

You've already got a solution implemented that can handle this. What you're describing is exactly what sockets are for -- bidirectional communication between the client and server without refreshing the page.

Just create a new socket listener on the frontend for a new topic, maybe "stageStatus", and then emit messages to that topic on the backend at various stages in the process. That's it!